# Strange SQL statement error using join

Tags: sql, oracle

This is not the first time I am writing SQL statement and it is really bizarre to me what why I keep getting this error.

```
   SELECT
   CASE WHEN  VENDORDELIVERY IS NOT NULL THEN VENDORDELIVERY   ELSE 'No Delivery' END as " Vendor Delivery No.",
        DATE_TIME as "Delivery Date/Time",
        'z0' AS "Icon1",
        'z0' AS "Icon2",
        'z0' AS "Icon3",
        'z0' AS "Icon4",
            NVL(completion,0) AS "Progress",
        'd0' AS "Active",
        MATERIALCODE as "Material Code",
        MATERIAL as "Material",
        DELIVERY_QTY as "Delivery Qty",
        ASN_UNLOADINGSTATION AS "Unload. Manf",
        ASN_DESTINATIONTANK AS "DEST. Tank",
        STATUS AS "Status" , 'NO_DATA' AS "NoData1"
  FROM  XVW_ASN_OVERVIEW z
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT 'NO_DATA' AS NoData2 FROM DUAL ) b  
  ON z.NoData1 = b.NoData2;
```

The error I am getting are ORA-00904: "Z"."NODATA1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 23 Column: 10

XVW_ASN_OVERVIEW is a view and I even try creating a column inside this view.

Both column are valid and when I run the SQL statement independently, no error occurs. So strange. Anything that I miss out ? Maybe I need another pair of eyes to point out my error.

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: If your table XVW_ASN_OVERVIEW doesn't contain a column named NoData1 then selecting it the way you do right now isn't going to work. You would need to put it within a subquery, and then join to that. You could also use CROSS JOIN in this case, since your second "table" contains only one row which seems like what you're trying to do.

Comment: The query runs fine now after adding the column in the view. Found something strange. I wanted to return 1 row from dual if no record found. Got it working on another query but this one not showing up. Do you see anything suspicious ?

Answer (score 1):

For NoData1, you use a quoted identifier in your select and a non-quoted identifiers in your join statement. So try changing

```
      STATUS AS "Status" , 'NO_DATA' AS "NoData1"
```

to

```
      STATUS AS "Status" , 'NO_DATA' AS NoData1
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I tested this approach but it didn't work. Adding a column in the view solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strange.  You can't use an alias defined in the `SELECT` elsewhere in the same query.

Instead, here is one solution:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN  VENDORDELIVERY IS NOT NULL THEN VENDORDELIVERY ELSE 'No Delivery' END) as " Vendor Delivery No.",
        DATE_TIME as "Delivery Date/Time",
       'z0' AS "Icon1",
       'z0' AS "Icon2",
       'z0' AS "Icon3",
       'z0' AS "Icon4",
        COALESCE(completion, 0) AS "Progress",
        'd0' AS "Active",
        MATERIALCODE as "Material Code",
        MATERIAL as "Material",
        DELIVERY_QTY as "Delivery Qty",
        ASN_UNLOADINGSTATION AS "Unload. Manf",
        ASN_DESTINATIONTANK AS "DEST. Tank",
        STATUS AS "Status",
        'NO_DATA' AS "NoData1"
  FROM ( SELECT 'NO_DATA' AS NoData2 FROM DUAL
       ) b LEFT JOIN
       XVW_ASN_OVERVIEW z
      b  
      ON 1 = 1;
```

That is, you don't really need a condition.

Note some other changes:

- I switched to a `LEFT JOIN`.  I find these much easier to follow -- because all the rows in the first table are kept.
- I prefer `COALESCE()` to `NVL()` because the former is ANSI standard.

Comment: Agree. I switch to COALESCE. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want one record saying "No_DATA" in case the query doesn't return any rows. For that you also need column NoData2. 
The parser wants to join the tables before it evaluates the selected columns, so it doesn't know you added NoData1. Unless you use your query as a temporary table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT 'NO_DATA' as NoData2 FROM DUAL) b
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  CASE WHEN  VENDORDELIVERY IS NOT NULL THEN VENDORDELIVERY   ELSE 'No Delivery' END as "Vendor Delivery No.",
  DATE_TIME as "Delivery Date/Time",
  'z0' AS "Icon1",
  'z0' AS "Icon2",
  'z0' AS "Icon3",
  'z0' AS "Icon4",
  NVL(completion,0) AS "Progress",
  'd0' AS "Active",
  MATERIALCODE as "Material Code",
  MATERIAL as "Material",
  DELIVERY_QTY as "Delivery Qty",
  ASN_UNLOADINGSTATION AS "Unload. Manf",
  ASN_DESTINATIONTANK AS "DEST. Tank",
  STATUS AS "Status" , 'NO_DATA' AS "NoData1"
FROM  XVW_ASN_OVERVIEW) Z
ON NoData1 = NoData2
```

Comment: Thanks... I just need to add the column in the view and it resolves the problem.